# How to deploy Asp.Net Core apps on Azure Service Fabric using subpaths sharing same port on the cluster

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-1.0

The Service Fabric samples like wordcount the web app listen on a port in a subpath like this:

http://localhost:8081/wordcount

The code for this configuration is: (See the file on GitHub https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/Services/WordCount/WordCount.WebService/WordCountWebService.cs)

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(initParams => new OwinCommunicationListener("wordcount", new Startup(), initParams))
            };
        }
```

With this configuration we can deploy other web apps on the same cluster using the same port (8081)

http://localhost:8081/wordcount

http://localhost:8081/app1

http://localhost:8081/app2

And so on.

But the Asp.Net Core project template is different and I don't know how to add the subpath on listener configuration.

The code below is what we have in the project template (Program.cs class WebHostingService):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
            {
                return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(_ => this) };
            }

Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);

                string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}";

                _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                               .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                               .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                               .Build();

                _webHost.Start();

                return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
            }
```

The semantic is a bit different, but all ends up in the same point.
The problems is that even I add the subpath at the end of serverUrl it does't work and the web apps always responds on the root http://localhost:8081/

See how I've tried in the code snippet below:

```
string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}/app1";
```

How to achieve the same result as "classic" web app using asp.net core?

The goal is to publish on azure on port 80 to let users with a better experience like:

http://mywebsite.com/app1

http://mywebsite.com/app2

Thank you a lot!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#service-fabric-integration-middleware

Comment: Great addition @LaPuyaLoca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kestrel doesn't support URL prefixes or port sharing between multiple applications. You have to use [WebListener](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#weblistener) instead:

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
...
_webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()`

Comment: Can you help with a sample? No combination that I've tried worked... Thank you a lot

Comment: Hey I am trying to create multiple instances of same service on my local machine. but as I deployed, first instances uses port A, other instances gave me error port A is already is in use. I am also using kestrel. Do you have solution for that? Also UseWebLister is not available.

Answer (score 4):

As @Vaclav said is necessary to change UseKestrel by UseWebListener.

But the problem is that WebListener binding to the address is different.

Look this thread to more details https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/749

Is necessary to use + instead of localhost or other machine names on the serverUrl.

So, change de template code from:

```
            Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);


            string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}/service1";

            _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                           .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                           .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                           .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                           .Build();

            _webHost.Start();

            return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
        }
```

To

```
            Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var endpoint = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetEndpoint(_endpointName);

                string serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://+:{endpoint.Port}/service1";

                _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()
                                               .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                               .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                               .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                               .Build();

                _webHost.Start();

                return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
            }
```

And it workd very well.

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this yet, but is this GitHub repository useful?

https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting

> About The Sample
>
> This sample demonstrates:
>
> 1.How ASP.NET Core can be used in a communication listener of stateless/stateful services. Today the scenario we've enabled is to host ASP.NET Core web application as a stateless service with Service Fabric. We wanted to light up the scenarios that people also can use ASP.NET Core as communication listeners in stateless services and stateful services, similar to what the OwinCommunicationListener does.
>
> 2.How to build an API gateway service to forward requests to multiple microservices behind it with the reusable and modular component. Service Fabric is a great platform for building microservices. The gateway middleware (Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Gateway) is an attempt to provide a building block for people to easily implement the API gateway pattern of microservices on Service Fabric. There are a couple good articles elaborating the API gateway pattern, such as http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html, http://www.infoq.com/articles/microservices-intro, etc. For more information about microservices, check out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/microservices-an-application-revolution-powered-by-the-cloud/, http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html.

Comment: With the sample approach is possible to run several Services on the same port using their names like:

http://localhost:20000/service1 <--- Svc in Application1

http://localhost:20000/service2 <--- Svc in Application1

This is possible because is there a Gateway service that maps the addresses service1 and service2 in the URI to the correct services.

But I couldn't find a way to have 2 different Applications running on the same port.

Is it possible?

http://localhost:20000/service1   <--- Svc in Application1

http://localhost:20000/service2   <--- Svc in Application2

Answer (score 1):

@Nick Randell

With the sample approach is possible to run several Services on the same port using their names like:

http://localhost:20000/service1 <--- Svc in Application1

http://localhost:20000/service2 <--- Svc in Application1

This is possible because is there a Gateway service that maps the addresses service1 and service2 in the URI to the correct services.

But I couldn't find a way to have 2 different Applications running on the same port.

Is it possible?

http://localhost:20000/service1   <--- Svc in Application1

http://localhost:20000/service2   <--- Svc in Application2